# Скидка при определенном методе оплаты

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Задача - применить купон 10% к корзине, если выбран метод оплаты - банковским платежом (bacs). Либо не купон, а как то по другому, но сделать скидку.

Пытался такими вариантами

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_discounted_price( $price, $values, $instance 
) { 
global $woocommerce;


if( $available_gateways['bacs']->chosen ) { 
    $discount = $price * 0.1;
}

return ($price - $discount); 
};


add_filter('woocommerce_get_discounted_price','filter_woocommerce_get_discounted_price', 
10, 3 );
```

В этом варианте не работает определение выбранного метода
**if( $available_gateways['bacs']->chosen ) {** 
потому что без него работает нормально

Вообщем нужно вставить такой код, в нужный хук (в какой именно не знаю), который подсчитывает итоговую цену корзины

```
 if( $available_gateways['bacs']->chosen ) { 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( 'online10' );
 }
 else {
    WC()->cart->remove_coupon( 'online10' );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это нужно вставить в хук, то надо делать так:

```
function add_discount($cart)
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || is_cart() ) {
        return;
    }

    if (WC()->session->chosen_payment_method == 'bacs') {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Скидка за метод', - $cart->cart_contents_total * 0.1 );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount' , 10 );
```

Код проверен на [моем тестовом сайте](http://test.kagg.eu) с методом оплаты Cash on Delivery.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А куда код вставляли? Вставил в functions.php. Код работает, но иногда не подгружается надпись "Скидка за метод", хотя при оплате сумма со скидкой появляется.

Comment: Вставлять надо в functions.php